# Message that database is updated after redirecting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP. I want to display a message that the database is updated after each time I redirect it after entering the data.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO incoming (recipt, userid, username, money)
VALUES ('$recipt', '$userid', '$username', '$money')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     echo "<script>window.open('incoming2.php','_self')</script>";  
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   

}
```

Comment: Why do you have an extra brace? Also look in to affected rows.

Comment: idnt  get ..... i want the data to be updated to the database after updating it should return the same page and should show a message that the database is updated

Comment: `window.open` will  replace your current page. Any code after that will not get executed. It will start from the beginning.

Comment: Is this all one page or 2 different pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 methods
1-you can redirect to any page adding message in get variable and check at that page if that variable is set then display it as message

```
//redirect to index.php with msg as
header('location:index.php?msg=2 records updated');

//at index page where you want to display message
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && !empty($_GET['msg'])){
    echo '<p class="myMsg">'.$_GET['msg'].'</p>'
}
```

2- second method is to save the message to session variable and access it at page but you will have to unset that variable as below

```
 //sending message assuming session_start() is written at to of all pages
 $_SESSION['msg']="2 records updated or what ever your message is";

//where you want to display message
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && !empty($_SESSION['msg'])){
    echo '<p class="myMsg">'.$_SESSION['msg'].'</p>'
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the message to your url:

```
echo "<script>window.open('incoming2.php?message=New+record+created+successfully','_self')</script>";
```

Then you can get the message in incoming2.php:

```
echo urldecode($_GET['message']);
```

Be careful: sanatize your input!

Answer (score 0):

Use `header("Location: incoming2.php");` instead of `echo`ing JS.

Also, check your SQL statement for [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the data on the same page you could do the following:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])){
        // mySQL code here
        // return either success or failed
        $confirmation="success";
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <?php 
            if(isset($confirmation)){
             echo $confirmation;
            } 
        ?>
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are sending the data to a separate page:

On the receiving page:

```
<?php
        // mySQL code here
        // return either success or failed
        //redirect to index.php with confirmation as true or false
        header('location:index.php?confirmation=success');

?>
```

and on the page that you Sent the data from:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <?php 

            //at index page where you want to display message
            if(isset($_GET['confirmation']) && !empty($_GET['confirmation'])){
                echo $_GET['confirmation'];
            }

        ?>
    </div>

    <form method="post" action="uploaddata.php">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

You can then use CSS3 animations to fade the message in and out for a better user experience :-)